# how to return error message from in controller rather than returning modelAndView in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am passing an id in controller from a list page, where it is getting processed and result is set in `model.addObject()`.

Also, I am setting view in new `ModelAndView("viewName")`. So the new data is shown on the new jsp. Now I am adding a logic that if the id passed from list page is same as userId in session, I need to show error message "You cannot do this as the user selected is yourslef" on same list page rather than showing new page with new data.

This is my method syntax.

```
    public ModelAndView showdetails(@RequestParam ("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin){....

    return modelAndView;
    }
```

Please suggest a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this method returns the view , you could map a object to it something like this ,

```
public ModelAndView showdetails(@RequestParam ("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin){....

    // Verify your session here   
    if (session.getAttribute("name").equals("name")
{
 string vale = "You cannot do this as the user selected is yourslef"    
 return modelAndView("viewname","value",value);
    }
```

And in your jsp ,

use EL to print it ,

```
${value}
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

It's done through JS. And your controller method should return
ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>>. When you select a user from a list page, in the function of onchange() event you send request by Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and you will get responseText and parse it on JSON. Then you will get the message and alter some content of your document to show it.

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> showdetails(@RequestParam("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin){
    Map<String,String> resp = new HashMap<>();
    if (session.getAttribute("name").equals("name")){
        resp.put("message","You cannot do this as the user selected is yourslef");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(resp);
}
```

Then your JS should be:

```
function checkUser(userId){
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url="https://your.domain.com/...";

        Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
            if (Http.readyState===Http.DONE && Http.responseText!=""){
                var json = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
                document.getElementById("msgElement").value=json['message'];
            }
        }

        Http.onerror = () => alert("Request failed");

    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();
}
```